# How to store the last counter value in css and display as content in html?

Tags: html, css, css-counter

For example, my CSS looks like this:

```
.page-number:after { counter-increment: page; }
```

When show as content, for example 6 pages:

```
.page-number:after { 
   content: 'Page ' counter(page) ' of';
}
```

I want to store the last counter -which is 6 - and print it out after each item. Is that possible to do that?

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: page;
  padding: 0;
}
.page-number {
  counter-increment: page;
}
.page-number:before {
  content: 'Page ' counter(page) ' of'
}
```

```html
<p>I want to use counters to print '6' after each item. eg. page 1 of 6 </p>
<ul>
  <li class="page-number"></li>
  <li class="page-number"></li>
  <li class="page-number"></li>
  <li class="page-number"></li>
  <li class="page-number"></li>
  <li class="page-number"></li>
</ul>
```

My `.page-number` is with position fixed, which will be display for all of the pages printed.

updated:

```
@media print {
body { margin: 0; }
thead { counter-reset: pages; }
.page-number:before { counter-increment: pages; content: " "; }
.page-number:after { counter-increment: page; }
.page-number:after { content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages); }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQNreQ

Comment: Have you tried `.page-number:last-child:after`?

Comment: @Huelfe how is it works?

Comment: Have a look at my answer @Crazy.

Comment: @Danield Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: I found no way to get the total, i tried some trick but it only show for first page and other pages will left empty such as 1 of 2 then 1 of ' '.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shown your html as below;
 1. Test
 2. Test
 3. Test

you can do so:

```
<div class="test">
  <h3>List Item</h3>
  <h3>List Item</h3>
  <h3>List Item</h3>
</div>
.test {
  counter-reset: page;
}
.test h3:before {
  counter-increment: page;
  content: page". ";
}
```

Comment: Not really. i want do it for printing. Need to do trick for getting last pages value

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: page;
}

.page-number:after { 
  counter-increment: page;
  content: counter(page);
  visibility: hidden;
}

.page-number:last-child:after { 
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="page-number">test</div>
  <div class="page-number">test</div>
  <div class="page-number">test</div>
  <div class="page-number">test</div>
  <div class="page-number">test</div>
  <div class="page-number">test</div>
</div>
```

You have to print the counter otherwise it would not increment. So I changed the visibility.

Comment: No, my page number is position fixed which will be display on every page of printed.

Comment: It is something like Page 1 of 6. I tried a lot of result but no luck. I tried my own way to show total but it will only display on first page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof of concept to show that this can be done with pure CSS:

1) Add one element after the page-list which stores the total amount of pages.

2) Make use of the [CSS element() function](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#element-notation) - Currently a draft in the Images Module Level 4 spec - but [supported by firefox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-element-function) since version 4 - to copy it's contents as a background to the other items.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element):

> The element() CSS function defines an  value generated from an
>   arbitrary HTML element. This image is live, meaning that if the HTML
>   element is changed, the CSS properties using the resulting value are
>   automatically updated.

### Demo snippet (View in firefox)

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: page;
}
.page-number {
  counter-increment: page;
  padding-right: 0.3em;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.page-number:before {
  content: 'Page ' counter(page) ' of'
}
.page-number ~ .page-number {
  background:-moz-element(#counterTotal) no-repeat right center;
  padding-right: 0.8em;
}
.copy:before {
  content: counter(page);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="page-number"></li>
  <li class="page-number"></li>
  <li class="page-number"></li>
  <li class="page-number"></li>
  <li class="page-number"></li>
  <li class="page-number"></li>
</ul>
<span id="counterTotal" class="copy"></span>
```

---

NB: I'm posting this answer as a proof of concept to show that *theoretically* this can actually be done with pure CSS (with the cost of adding one extra element). That being said, I would certainly recommend using **a javascript solution** here.

Comment: How do i apply in my case? I know how to do this, but still i cant get the result i want when printing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.page-number:after
    {
       counter-increment: page;
       content: counter(page) "/" counter(pages);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had to build something similar recently.
I found a brute-force solution.

Using SASS:

```
.page {
  counter-increment: page;

  @for $i from 1 through 100 {
    &:nth-last-child(#{$i})::after,
    &:nth-last-child(#{$i}) ~ &::after {
      content: "Page " counter(page) " of #{$i}.";
    } 
  }
}
```

As you can imagine, it outputs quite a lot of CSS:

```
.page {
  counter-increment: page;
}
.page:nth-last-child(1)::after, .page:nth-last-child(1) ~ .page::after {
  content: "Page " counter(page) " of 1.";
}
.page:nth-last-child(2)::after, .page:nth-last-child(2) ~ .page::after {
  content: "Page " counter(page) " of 2.";
}
.page:nth-last-child(3)::after, .page:nth-last-child(3) ~ .page::after {
  content: "Page " counter(page) " of 3.";
}
/* etc… */
```

Answer (score -1):

You can work with "CSS Counters"

For example

```css
body {
    counter-reset: section;
}

h2::before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: "Section " counter(section) ": ";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Using CSS Counters:</h1>
<h2>HTML Tutorial</h2>
<h2>CSS Tutorial</h2>
<h2>JavaScript Tutorial</h2>

<p><b>Note:</b> IE8 supports these properties only if a !DOCTYPE is specified.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Source
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp

Comment: Mostly taken from [this W3Schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_gen_counter-reset) and butchered in such a way as to make that IE8 note a complete non-sequitur by changing the :before to ::before (which, hilariously, [another W3Schools example also does](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_counters3)).